# Linear Partial Differential Equations with no solutions: known examples

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

As it is clearly explained
[here](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/pdectb/lewy2.pdf) by L. N. Trefethen, not every linear partial differential equation has a solution (not even in the sense of distribution theory). The referred example is the one given by Hans Lewy in 1957 in [Annals of Mathematics](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970121).

There exists a $C^\infty$ real function $f=f(t)$ such that the nonhomogeneous linear equation

$ \displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} -2i(x+iy) \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = f(t),$

has no solution.

As stated by K. O. Friedrichs:

> Once it is said, it is clear to everybody;
>   but Lewy was the first to say it!

Other than the PDEs in the first link or in the references therein, are there other known linear partial differential that fail to have a solution?

Comment: There was a typo: the second derivative should be for $y$ as you said. I edited the question and now it is correct. Tks.

Comment: Note tle last paragraph on the first page of your first link. In particular: "This means that the set of $C^\infty$ functions for which $Pu = f$ has no solution near any point is very much larger than the set of $f$ for which a solution to this equation exists."

Comment: I have edited the question in order to clarify your observations. Tks.